# Drupal 7 my paragraphs are not looking right

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-7, paragraphs

was testing drupal 7 on my computer. I used a basic theme and a good looking freebie (Bluemasters). Looking good, but as I went to edit/add some content, specifically paragraphs and images. The images don't appear when I save it, and the paragraphs are crunched or packed together too close, like there was no top or bottom margins, I checked the css but it looked fine. Is there something else that needs to be configured on the chosen template? What am I missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely the text format for your body field is set to 'Filtered HTML' when you need it to be set to 'Full HTML'. These are the tags that are allowed in 'Filtered HTML' by default:

```
<a> <em> <strong> <cite> <blockquote> <code> <ul> <ol> <li> <dl> <dt> <dd>
```

`<p>` and `<img>` are not allowed in that list which is why they're currently missing.

If you change the text format to 'Full HTML' and save the node again it should work OK.

I often visit `admin/config/content/formats` when starting a project and drag the 'Full HTML' format to the top of the list so it becomes the site default from then on.